# exec format error when trying to excute a python excutable in golang

Tags: go, compiler-errors, command-line-interface

Im trying to write a cli that execute a python file from https://github.com/timeopochin/GanTTY. When excute in terminal using

```
python3 ./GanTTY/main.py gantt test
```

it will create a new interactive gantt chart. However when i do this in my go code, like this

```
{
  Name: "project",
  Usage: "add a new project with gantt chart",
  Action: func(c *cli.Context) error {
      cmd := exec.Command("./GanTTY/main.py", "gantt", "test")
      err:= cmd.Run()
      if err != nil {
          log.Fatal(err)
      }
      fmt.Println("opend project")
      return nil
  },
},
```

and run the go program

```
go run program.go add project //"add" and "project" are command and sub command
```

it gives me this error

```
2022/04/03 11:42:19 fork/exec ./GanTTY/main.py: exec format error
exit status 1
```

Comment: You need to call the python interpreter: `exec.Command("/usr/bin/python3","./GanTTY/main.py", "gantt", "test")`

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `python3` or `cmd.exe /c python3` in windows.

```
cmd := exec.Command("python3","GanTTY/main.py", "gantt", "test")
```

use cmd.Dir to set directory of python file relative to current wd

```
cmd := exec.Command("python3","main.py", "gantt", "test")
cmd.Dir = "GanTTY"
```